# Autofocus on EditorFor

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I would like to autofocus on an editorfor in my application, but I can't seem to do that. I have successfully used autofocus on a textbox, but I would like to use an editorfor to keep my application's look universal.

Any solutions to this would be much appreciated, thank you.

My attempt:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }, autofocus = "" })
```

Comment: @DavidG yes I have tried that too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This s because you are using EditorFor instead of something specific like TextBoxFor.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { 
                    @class = "form-control" }, autofocus="autofocus"})
```

Or you can do that using jQuery:

```
<div class="editor-field focus">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
</div> 
$(function() {
    $('.focus :input').focus();
});
```

**Update**:
As you know `TextBoxFor` always creates a textbox with type input, But `EditorFor` is a little bit smart, it renders markup based on the datatype of the property.

Comment: Are you saying in order to use autofocus there can be no ambiguity of the input data type?

Comment: @Jon If you look at the overloads for EditorFor, there aren't any overload that accept htmlAttributes. The overload you are using actually is taking additionalViewData.

Comment: Thank you, I am fairly new to asp.net and have not learned much jQuery yet, but your jQuery solution worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 9):

Using .Net Framework 4.5 and MVC 5, this works for me:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new {
    htmlAttributes = new {
        @class = "form-control",
        autofocus = true
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You put the autofocus attribute in the wrong spot.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, 
     new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }, autofocus = "" })
```

Try this instead:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, 
     new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", autofocus = "" } })
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been following this thread and I may have stumbled on an answer to your question about autofocus on EditorFor - this is all Asp.Net 4.5 and MVC 5, not that it matters.

1. In the Scripts folder I have a jQuery script file:

   $(function(){
   $('.someclassname').focus();
   });

I add the script name to the BundleConfig and render it in the view.

2. In the view I add the classname to the EditorFor `<div class="col-md-10" someclassname">`
3. I then add the `type="text" autofocus="autofocus"` to the EditorFor's @class. So, `new{@class="form-control", type="text", autofocus="autofocus"`
4. That's pretty much it, when the DOM loads the `.someclassname` field gets the cursor focus...
   PS.  In fact if you just do (3) it works also...