# Setting focus on EditorFor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Trying to set default focus to the following field, but having trouble. Have tried multiple solutions that seemed straight forward, but none are working and I don't know why since these were all highly upvoted answers for mvc 5.1+

Was trying to do without using javascript or switching it to `TextBoxFor()`

Below are some of them, have also tried some close variations to these.

Any help would be appreciated. Using mvc 5.2 & razor 3.0

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.FirstName, new { style = "Width:100px" })
```

//I know the above isn't focus, since I wasn't 100% sure on my syntax, but this doesn't change my width either.

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }})

@Html.EditorFor(x => x.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { autofocus = "autofocus" } })
```

Edit:
Have also tried

```
@Html.EditorFor(x=> x.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", autofocus = "" } })

@Html.EditorFor(x=> x.FirstName, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control", autofocus = true}})
```

Update - Solution :

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.FirstName, new { html = new { autofocus = "autofocus" } })
```

This ended up working, htmlAttributes wasn't working, changing it to html did it.

Comment: To which "highly upvoted answers" are you referring? The first I had found is this, and it won't make you happy. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32169014/autofocus-on-editorfor (Edit: Voted duplicate)

Comment: `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", autofocus = "autofocus" }})`

Comment: @thmshd, The top answer on that dupe is simply wrong for  mvc 5.1+ (its the answers by Patrick and Steve M that are correct)

Comment: I've tried the answers by Pat & Steve M as well, but they aren't working which leads back to my original question.

Comment: @user273870,What is not working? The code **WILL** add the `autofocus` attribute.

Comment: Using 'htmlAttributes' was keeping it from working. Changing it to 'html' like I put in my update made it work.

Comment: Using `html` cannot possibly work unless you had a custom `EditorTemplate` for `string`!